# Algorithm notation between two functions

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I have two functions,
$$ f = n^{1.6} $$
$$ g = n^{1.5} $$

I thought this is $ f=\theta(g) $, since $ f $ is asymptotically tight bound of $ g $, if $ n $ goes to infinity.
 However, the answer is  $ f = \omega(g) $. 
Can anyone explain why it is $ f = \omega(g) $ ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "$f$ is asymptotically tight bound of $g$"? Are you sure you have understood the definition of $\Theta$?

Comment: @dkaeae I think so. The definition of $ theta $ is, $ 0 <= c_1 g(n) <= f(n) <= c_2 g(n) $ for $ 0<= c_1 <= c_2 $. I thought $ x^{0.1} $(their difference) really does not matter if $ x $ goes to infinity. That's why I am thinking it is $ theta $.

Comment: That difference *does* matter. $x^\varepsilon$ is unbounded for any $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: @dkaeae Okay. what if the difference is 0.000001 like very small number. Does it still matter? Just want to make sure.

Comment: In mathematics, "very small" is a relative notion. $0.000001$ is gigantic compared to $10^{-100}$. It does not matter as long as it is strictly greater than zero.

Comment: Try computing $n^{0.000001}$ where $n = 42^{1000000}$. Then replace 42 with a larger number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \frac{n^{1.6}}{n^{1.5}} = n^{0.1}$ is unbounded. Hence, for any $c > 0$ there is $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n^{0.1} > c$ for all $n > n_0$. As a result, for any $c > 0$, we have $n^{1.6} = n^{0.1} \cdot n^{1.5} > c n^{1.5}$ for all $n > n_0$.

Notice this does not really make use of $1.5$ and $1.6$ other than $1.6 > 1.5$. In fact, using the same method and the fact that $n^\varepsilon$ is unbounded for any $\varepsilon > 0$, you can prove the more general bound $n^a \in \omega(n^b)$ for any $a > b \ge 0$.